# are there text-filtering filters for IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, performance, indexeddb

I have a database of about 64000 products, and when I'm trying to find some with certain text in the name, I need to iterate over all 64000 of them, checking each one individually with a function.

Is there a better way to have IndexedDB return only objects where the value matches a certain regexp or contains a certain string?

Comment: something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB#Using_an_index ?

Comment: no. that document explains basically how to set up an IndexedDB database. I've already got one up and running. I'm trying to retrieve rows that match a string pattern. As far as I can see, the specs only define numerical bounds for cursors - not string pattern filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

I think the closest you can get to this is storing an array of keywords together with your string data, and then use a multiEntry index. You could retrieve a list of objects containing any particular keyword, though you must make an intersection of results yourself if you want to query for multiple words at once.

Comment: hmm... that means I would need to know every probable search before it happens. the database index would be /huge/.

Comment: How do you mean knowing every probable search? You just get an index the size of 64000*[average number of keywords]. You'd compute the intersection when people search, not for indexing. At least, that's what I had in mind.

Comment: ah - I understand what you mean. That would solve one half of the question (finding by string), but not the other half (finding by regexp).

It's a good solution, though - a bit like fulltext in relational db?